# Find the convergence domain of the following series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the convergence domain of the following series

$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{9}+...$$ such that the coefficients are given by $a_{2m} = 2^{-m} , a_{2m+1} = 3^{-m}$.

I'm having a little bit of trouble and am wondering if I could have any help? Thanks

Comment: What standard techniques have you tried?

Comment: What criteria are available to you in regards of finding the radius of convergence of a power series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two analytic functions in a neighbourhood of the origin, $f(x)$ with radius of convergence $\sqrt{2}$ and $g(x)$ with radius of convergence $\sqrt{3}$. It follows that $g(x)+f(x)$ is an analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin with radius of convergence $\min(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\color{blue}{\sqrt{2}}$. Thus the domain of convergence is a subset of $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ and you just have to study what happens at the endpoints.

Comment: Congrats, the diamond suits you well